# How to get the full log error message from Grafana into Alertmanager for alerting?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, prometheus-alertmanager

I can get the labels from the log messages on Grafana for which I am alerting through alertmanager. However, I want to get the full log message into the alert message that gets sent to slack or email. Is it possible somehow? I have tried .Labels.Message and .Labels.MessageTemplate but they don't work.